# Python: Calculating the angle between two bones in an x-ray

Tags: python, image, opencv, graph, hough-transform

I am trying to write a script to calculate the angle between two bones given an x-ray.

A sample x-ray would look like the following:

[image: Sample x-ray]

I am trying to calculate the midline of each bone, essentially a line following the midpoints of the two sides of a bone, and then compare the angle between the two midlines.

I have tried using OpenCV to get the outline of the bones, but it does not seem accurate enough and gets lots of extra data. I am stuck on how to move next and how I would calculate the midline. I am quite new to image processing but have experience with Python.

Getting edges using OpenCV results:

[image]

Code for OpenCV:

```
import cv2

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("xray-3.jpg")

# Find the contours
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,60,200)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0] # get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions

# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and draw it
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

# Finally show the image
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Any chance to get the data without the stupid super-edgy super-white text labels?

Comment: Use a classifier to read the wide base / narrow bone. You should find two, one up/ one down.  Then perform horizontal scans left to right across the bone black to white to black. place a dot in center. Perform multiple scans at different vertical locations.  Connect the dots within each classifier to define the angle of that bone.

Comment: @zipzit *horizontal* scans would systematically shift the center of the intersection of the horizontal line with bone to left/right relative to the center of the bone, because the bone itself is not orthogonal to horizontal lines, and its boundary is concave, not linear. What I want to say: to find the center by "horizontal" scans, you would have to make the scans in the orthogonal direction of the bone, but for that you would have to know the angle of the bone, and that's what we wanted to find in the first place...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin . Nope.  Take a piece of paper, a straight edge and a pencil.  Try it.  I don't know the correct geometry description.. its the way a carpenter in 1700's would use a ruler to subdivide a measurement easily.  Really old skool.  Maybe that happened in the 1600's.  You could scan at any angle, as long as both ends of the scan cross the bone in the area away from the joint. You just want to place a dot in the middle, then connect the dots. [Link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Subdividing-Lines-Without-a-Calculator/)

Comment: @zipzit The problem is that there is no "area away from the joint" on the xray-image, at least it's not far enough to approximate the image of the bone as a rectangle with two parallel sides. This is a reasonable approximation for small angles of the bones, but if it is exactly the small angle that we are after, I don't think that this would give a particularly good approximation.

Comment: oops.  I guess that really depends on exactly what bone angles we're talking about.  The question as worded doesn't really make that clear.  I'm assuming its the angle between the left lower leg bone and the left thigh bone in this view. (repeat for right side) It sounds like my assumption of what's being measured doesn't remotely match your assumption.  Too bad I can't submit a sketch to my comments...

Comment: @schaudhry123  I do have one question.  Are the sides of the X-ray ALWAYS vertical?  I'm pretty sure gravity always points down.  And I'm pretty sure folks are standing upright when these are taken (else a bone angle measurement wouldn't make sense...) . Can we use that to our advantage?

Comment: I believe so, all of the xrays are vertical. That's a really interesting idea actually. The only worry I have is that it is definitely possible for some of the xrays to be slightly tilted/off vertical. Not sure if we could assume the bones are directly vertical.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not cheating, i'd recommend cropping the image to not in include as much of the labels and scales as possible without removing any areas of interest.

That being said, I think your method of getting the contours will be usable if you do some preprocessing to the image. One algorithm that might do the trick is a [Difference of Gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians) (DoG) filter which will bring out the edges a little more. I modified slightly [this code](https://gist.github.com/leonidk/8798fdbf38db120b8536d25ea2f8c3b4) which will compute the DoG filter using a few different *sigma* and *k* values.

```
from skimage import io, feature, color, filters, img_as_float
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

raw_img = io.imread('xray-3.jpg')
original_image = img_as_float(raw_img)
img = color.rgb2gray(original_image)

k = 1.6

plt.subplot(2,3,1)
plt.imshow(original_image)
plt.title('Original Image')

for idx,sigma in enumerate([4.0, 8.0, 16.0, 32.0]):
    s1 = filters.gaussian(img, k*sigma)
    s2 = filters.gaussian(img, sigma)

    # multiply by sigma to get scale invariance
    dog = s1 - s2
    plt.subplot(2,3,idx+2)
    print("min: {} max: {}".format(dog.min(), dog.max())
    plt.imshow(dog, cmap='RdBu')
    plt.title('DoG with sigma=' + str(sigma) + ', k=' + str(k))

ax = plt.subplot(2, 3, 6)
blobs_dog = [(x[0], x[1], x[2]) for x in feature.blob_dog(img, min_sigma=4, max_sigma=32, threshold=0.5, overlap=1.0)]
# skimage has a bug in my version where only maxima were returned by the above
blobs_dog += [(x[0], x[1], x[2]) for x in feature.blob_dog(-img,  min_sigma=4, max_sigma=32, threshold=0.5, overlap=1.0)]

#remove duplicates
blobs_dog = set(blobs_dog)

img_blobs = color.gray2rgb(img)
for blob in blobs_dog:
    y, x, r = blob
    c = plt.Circle((x, y), r, color='red', linewidth=2, fill=False)
    ax.add_patch(c)
plt.imshow(img_blobs)
plt.title('Detected DoG Maxima')

plt.show()
```

[image]

At first glance, it appears that sigma=8.0, k=1.6 might be your best bet as this seems to best exaggerate the edges of the lower leg while getting rid of the noise across it. Particularly over that of the subjects left (image right) leg. Give your edge detection another go and play around with *k* and *sigma* and let me know what you get :)

If the results look good you should be able to get a center point between the edges detected for either leg in each row of the image. Then just find the line of best fit for the mid points for either leg and you should be good to go. You will also need to isolate one leg from another, so again, if it's not cheating, maybe crop the image down the middle into two images.

Comment: This is great! It is definitely possible to crop the image to get rid of the labels and extra info or even get individual legs. I'll try this out now. Thank you for this, this is exactly what I was looking for!